# Unable to access directory created under Network Share in Windows 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

Gettting below error in accessing folder created under Network Share:- "Windows cannot access \Network_Share\XYZ."

"You do not have permission to access \Network_Share\XYZ. Contact your
network administrator to request access."
Whereas, able to access network share(\Network_Share) from any machine. Only XYZ folder is not accessible.

Kindly suggest please.......

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have permission access XYZ folder. To check this
Right click on the XYZ folder and go to Properties>Security tab and check whether your ID is having permission to access the folder (You can use "Effective Permission" under the Advance option in Security Tab)
Also check permission in Share tab too.